# Linkage#registerBootstrapMethod in JDK 7

Tags: java, java-7, invokedynamic

Back in the preview releases of JDK 7 there was a collection of  methods which controled the linkage of invokedynamic call sites in a class called Linkage. For example `registerBootstrapMethod`. What happend to these in the final release of the JDK?

Answer (score 1):

The invokedynamic instruction itself has now a reference to the bootstrap method